# Finding the value of n from logarithmic equation

Tags: logarithms

What will be the approach of finding $n$, where my equation is $$n\log_2n = m$$ 

I am trying to reaching  solution like ,where n = eqn . A simple approach would be very much helpful.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Lambert W Function. (You can Google it)

Comment: Here is a link: [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: n = (m Log[2])/ProductLog[m Log[2]]

Comment: Are n & m real? If you want a closed form, you need the Lambert W. If you just want to compute n, and you don't have the Lambert W, and you don't need to handle complex or negative numbers, then Newton's method normally converges fairly quickly (although inverting $y = x^x$ via Newton's near $x=e^{-1}$ is slow).